# Hadoop Put command for two files

Tags: hdfs

A file named records.txt from local to HDFS can be copied by using below command

```
hadoop dfs -put /home/cloudera/localfiles/records.txt /user/cloudera/inputfiles
```

By using the above command the file records.txt will be copied into HDFS with the same name.

But I want to store two files(records1.txt and demo.txt) into HDFS

I know that we can use something like below

```
hadoop dfs -put /home/cloudera/localfiles/records* /user/cloudera/inputfiles
```

but Is there any command that will help us to store one or two files with different names to be copied into hdfs ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With put command argument, you could provide one or multiple source files as mentioned [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/hdfs_shell.html#put). So try something like:

```
hadoop dfs -put /home/cloudera/localfiles/records* /home/cloudera/localfiles/demo* /user/cloudera/inputfiles
```

From hadoop shell command usage:

```
put

Usage: hadoop fs -put <localsrc> ... <dst>

Copy single src, or multiple srcs from local file system to the destination filesystem. Also reads input from stdin and writes to destination filesystem.

hadoop fs -put localfile /user/hadoop/hadoopfile
hadoop fs -put localfile1 localfile2 /user/hadoop/hadoopdir
hadoop fs -put localfile hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/hadoopfile
hadoop fs -put - hdfs://nn.example.com/hadoop/hadoopfile
Reads the input from stdin.

Exit Code:

Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using copyFromLocal coomand as follows :

hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/pig$ hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/user/Downloads/records1.txt /home/user/Downloads/demo.txt /user/pig/output